# Rails flash message not being created from validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

I've Googled and Stack Overflowed for hours and still can't find a solution to my problem.

I need a flash message to show from a validation in my Rails model but it doesn't want to happen.

Here's the validation in the model:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: {message: "that artist already added"}
```

I even have this in my controller as a fallback:

```
class BandsController < ApplicationController

def create

  @band = Band.create(id: params[:id])

  if @band.save
    flash[:message] = "Saved."
  else
    flash[:message] = "Nope."
  end

  render nothing: true, status: 201

end
```

But no dice.

And in my application.html.erb I've got the

```
<div class="flash_success">
  <%= flash[:message] %> 
</div>

<%= yield %>
```

I feel like something should happen, if not from the validation in the model, then with the save success in the controller. The div even appears when I inspect the page but alas, no message.

Why is nothing being printed to the DOM here?

Thanks for any guidance.

---

#### UPDATE

I should probably mention that I'm using jQuery to display my HTML, not a Rails view file. I know it may not be ideal but in this case it works for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
flash[:message] = "Something"
render nothing: true, status: 201
```

With you `render nothing: true`, you are halting the executing of the message rendering. Instead you should redirect to to somewhere & then you will notice the `flash[:message]` being rendered in your DOM.

May be :

```
def create
  @band = Band.create(id: params[:id])

  if @band.save
    flash[:message] = "Saved."
  else
    flash[:message] = "Nope."
  end

  render bands_path #moving to the band listing page.
end
```

Still without rendering if you want to have the flash then you need to make use of javascript.Check following code :

```
 1. remove that render nothing: true statement. 
 2.  app/views/bands/create.js.erb 
    $('#flash_div').text("<%= flash[:message] %>");
```

After your create action, the create.js.erb will be executed. This code will search for #flash_div, in the current DOM Structure & injects your flash content.

Comment: I think that's probably the issue, but sadly all my html is being rendered with an .appendTo() via a .js file, not a Rails erb file. So not sure how I'd go about redirecting to that file. Any ideas?

Comment: Drat. Followed your directions to the T but still nothing is being injected into that div. Even adding the closing ruby tag in  `<%= flash[:message]  %>`

Comment: Here "#flash_div" is the div where you want to render your flash. in your case <div class='flash_success'> so you need to use $('.flash_success'). 

Please paste your application.html.erb code. I will prepare the exact code for you.

Comment: The application.html.erb code is what appears above. I'm using `$('.flash_success').text("<%= flash[:message] %>");` in my create.js.erb like you advised (and took out the render statement in the controller), so I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: When I inspect the DOM the flash_success div is there, just empty. No matter what get saved or not saved.

Comment: hey this javascript will be executed when you submit to the create action with ajax submission not by http post submit. make sure your submit link &  form_for holds remote: true option & in your console you must notice this is submitted by JS not HTML submit. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69785/discussion-between-panicbus-and-ajay).

Answer (score 0):

When you use render, pls use "flash.now" and when you use choose to redirecting use "flash". Change the above as below. For more info, see documentation([flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash))

```
class BandsController < ApplicationController

def create

  @band = Band.create(id: params[:id])

  if @band.save
    flash.now[:message] = "Saved."
  else
    flash.now[:message] = "Nope."
  end

  render nothing: true, status: 201

end
```